# Wanted : sharing twitter blocklists tool called ichbinhier-twittertools.herokuapp

Tags: twitter

I am searching for this tool or an equivalent of this tool, that was VERY useful.

https://ichbinhier-twittertools.herokuapp.com/

This tool lets you export a list of blocked accounts on Twitter, share it and reimport it into another account.
Please help.

Sorry this is the first time I use Stackoverflow